# Moral Relativism Has To Fall Into One Of Two Categories. Where Does It Fall?

Tags: apologetics, morality, logic

Christian apologetics often has to confront the argument that there are at least three distinct moral possibilities - moral absolutism, moral relativism, and moral nihilism.  Moral relativism is often used by people that are uncomfortable with the two polarizing options of moral absolutism and moral nihilism.  *But maybe they don't have the choice between the two polarizing options that they think they have.*

---

Consider the following statement:

Whatever moral principles are, we can assume that either they can be destroyed by man, or they cannot be destroyed by man.

---

Now, consider the following groups:

Group A = group of philosophies where EVERY moral principle in each philosophy can be destroyed by man.

Group B = group of philosophies where at least one moral principle in each philosophy CANNOT be destroyed by man.

---

Logically, no philosophy can exist outside of both of these groups.  A philosophy must fall into one or the other.  Anything that even slightly deviates from Group A automatically goes into Group B.

Now I ask: **Which group would moral relativism fit into?**

*(I would classify Group A as a definition for moral nihilism and Group B as a definition for moral absolutism - although I'm sure not everybody would agree)*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 
"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"
Philosophy.SE

Comment: Thing is that Philosophy.SE has a criterion of not pushing a personal philosophy

Comment: This belongs on SE-Philosophy. This is nothing to do with the subject of Christianity.

Comment: "*Now I ask: Which group would moral relativism fit into?*" — That sounds like a rhetorical question.  If you eventually find a more appropriate place to ask, I'd follow that question with either, reasons you think it belongs in neither, or reasons you think it belongs in both. But as stated, it could simply be answered by "Group __" without any explanation. And then a dialog of questions and answers would follow. So, even if this item *were* suitable for this site, asking for a conversational answer is not allowed here (or on *any* Stack Exchange site).

Comment: I guess I'm unclear on what is suitable for stack exchange sites.  I figured they were open forums similar to Reddit.

Comment: The Stack Exchange model is academic in principle and Moderated in practice. It is neither social media nor a debate. To some extent, the whole community (once a certain level of individual reputation is gained by contribution) plays a part in moderation and control of content.